Select counts from one table based in the results from another table
I have two tables, lets call them t1 and t2. Fiddle
select setseed(.42);

create table t1(a,b,c,d)as
select (random()*9)::int
     , (random()*9)::int
     , (random()*9)::int
     , (random()*9)::int
from generate_series(1,100);

create table t2(a,b,c,d)as
select (random()*9)::int
     , (random()*9)::int
     , (random()*9)::int
     , (random()*9)::int
from generate_series(1,200);

I'm trying to filter t2 and count based on my results from a t1 selected query. This would be an inefficient working example (takes half an hour to finish):
SELECT *,
  SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.A = T1.A) AS cnt1,
  SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.A = T1.A AND t2.B = T1.B) AS cnt2,
  SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.A = T1.A AND t2.B = T1.B AND t2.C = T1.C) AS cnt3,
  SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.A = T1.A AND t2.B = T1.B AND t2.C = T1.C AND t2.D = T1.D) AS cnt4,
   ... and so on ...

FROM t1 WHERE A>B AND 1.5>C AND D-E>A

And this is what I'm trying to do using CTE:
SELECT *,
  (WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.A = T1.A),
   CTE2 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE1 WHERE t2.B = T1.B),
   CTE3 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE2 WHERE t2.C = T1.C),
   CTE4 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE3 WHERE t2.D = T1.D)
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE) AS cnt1,
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE2) AS cnt2,
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE3) AS cnt3,
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE3) AS cnt4
   )

FROM t1 WHERE A>B AND 1.5>C AND D-E>A

This only allows to return a single result, ex. cnt1. My guess is that maybe I can pass the result as an array like the example above, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.
SELECT *,
  (WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.A = T1.A),
   CTE2 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE1 WHERE t2.B = T1.B),
   CTE3 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE2 WHERE t2.C = T1.C),
   CTE4 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE3 WHERE t2.D = T1.D)
     ARRAY (SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE) ,
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE2),
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE3),
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE3))
   ) AS CNT[]

FROM t1 WHERE A>B AND 1.5>C AND D-E>A


EDIT: This would be a simplified example of my tables and expected
result.

fiddle
create table t1(id,a,b,c) as 
 values(1,2,1,1),
       (2,3,2,2),
       (3,1,3,3),
       (4,2,4,4),
       (5,3,5,5),
       (6,1,2,6),
       (7,2,2,7),
       (8,3,2,8),
       (9,4,2,9),
       (10,5,4,1);

create table t2(id,a,b,c) as 
 values(1,2,1,1),
       (2,3,2,2),
       (3,1,3,1),
       (4,2,4,4),
       (5,3,5,5),
       (6,1,2,6),
       (7,2,2,7),
       (8,3,2,8),
       (9,4,3,9),
       (10,5,4,1),
       (11,3,2,2),
       (12,4,4,4),
       (13,5,6,5),
       (14,3,2,3),
       (15,2,2,7),
       (16,1,2,8),
       (17,4,1,9),
       (18,5,2,5),
       (19,6,3,6),
       (20,7,4,7);

so updating my faulty query for this example:
SELECT *,   
 (WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.A = T1.A),    
  CTE2 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE1 WHERE t2.B = T1.B),   
  CTE3 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE2 WHERE t2.C = T1.C)
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE) AS cnt1,
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE2) AS cnt2,
     SELECT 
       (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CTE3) AS cnt3    
   ) 
 FROM t1 WHERE A>B AND C>1.5 



It sounds like you're trying to join the two tables on A, get a regular total count(*) as cnt1, then also count(*)filter(where t2.b=t1.b)as cnt2 and so on. The aggregate filter clause lets you do that in a single flat query, in a single pass.

For clarity, please provide a complete [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Refering to your last sample data with expected result (the result seems to be wrong) maybe you could use something like below:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
create table t1(id,a,b,c) as 
  values(1,2,1,1), (2,3,2,2), (3,1,3,3), (4,2,4,4), (5,3,5,5),
        (6,1,2,6), (7,2,2,7), (8,3,2,8), (9,4,3,9), -- it is (9,4,2,9)  in your fiddle but (9,4,3,9) in your result
        (10,5,4,1);

create table t2(id,a,b,c) as 
  values(1,2,1,1), (2,3,2,2), (3,1,3,1), (4,2,4,4), (5,3,5,5),
        (6,1,2,6), (7,2,2,7), (8,3,2,8), (9,4,3,9), (10,5,4,1),
        (11,3,2,2), (12,4,4,4), (13,5,6,5), (14,3,2,3), (15,2,2,7),
        (16,1,2,8), (17,4,1,9), (18,5,2,5), (19,6,3,6), (20,7,4,7);

1st - filter t1 to just rows of interest (id 2, 8 and 9)
WITH
  t1_filtered AS
    ( SELECT   t1.*
      FROM     t1 
      WHERE    a > b And c > 1.5
    )

... then cross join t2 with filtered data and use conditional aggregation to fetch the counts ...
--      S Q L : 
Select     t.id, t.a, t.b, t.c,
           Count(Distinct Case When t2.a = t.a Then t2.id End) as cnt1,
           Count(Distinct Case When t2.a = t.a And t2.b = t.b Then t2.id End) as cnt2, 
           Count(Distinct Case When t2.a = t.a And t2.b = t.b And t2.c = t.c Then t2.id End) as cnt3
From       t1_filtered t
Cross Join t2 
Group By   t.id, t.a, t.b, t.c
Order By   t.id

R e s u l t :



id
a
b
c
cnt1
cnt2
cnt3




2
3
2
2
5
4
2


8
3
2
8
5
4
1


9
4
3
9
3
1
1



fiddle
... with randomly generated data it would be like in the fiddle

This is exactly what i needed, thank you so much!

The aggregate filter clause lets you do that in a single flat query, in a single pass.
demo at db<>fiddle
select count(*)as cnt1
     , count(*)filter(where t2.b=t1.b)as cnt2 
     , count(*)filter(where t2.b=t1.b 
                        and t2.c=t1.c)as cnt3
     , count(*)filter(where t2.b=t1.b 
                        and t2.c=t1.c 
                        and t2.d=t1.d)as cnt4
from t1
join t2 using(a)
--where t1.a>t1.b 
--  and 1.5>t1.c 
--  and t1.d-t1.e>t1.a;




cnt1
cnt2
cnt3
cnt4




2031
225
17
2



If you're fine with getting that in rows, not columns, you can make those matches/mismatches your grouping sets or a rollup.
select t1.b=t2.b as b
     , t1.c=t2.c as c
     , t1.d=t2.d as d
     , grouping(t1.b=t2.b,t1.c=t2.c,t1.d=t2.d)
     , count(*)
from t1
join t2 using(a)
group by rollup(t1.b=t2.b,t1.c=t2.c,t1.d=t2.d)
having null is not distinct from nullif((t1.b=t2.b and t1.c=t2.c and t1.d=t2.d),true)
order by grouping;




b
c
d
grouping
count




t
t
t
0
2


t
t
null
1
17


t
null
null
3
225


null
null
null
7
2031



The use of grouping() helps if you want to skip/hide the individual columns. Having is there to hide the counts of mismatches.



b
c
d
grouping
count




t
t
t
0
2


f
t
f
0
148


t
t
f
0
15


f
f
t
0
163


t
f
t
0
19


t
f
f
0
189


f
t
t
0
26


f
f
f
0
1469


t
f
null
1
208


t
t
null
1
17


f
f
null
1
1632


f
t
null
1
174


t
null
null
3
225


f
null
null
3
1806


null
null
null
7
2031



Note that if the columns are nullable, having would have to change and grouping() would be necessary to tell the difference between a grouping set where the column isn't involved and one where the comparison actually yielded null.

Thanks for de reply, but i need all the rows selected from t1 and counts from t2 matching every listed row of t1

@MarioOrozco You're right, I overlooked that but a fix will be fairly simple. If you could please add your data sample as text, not a picture, it would make things easier to demonstrate. Even better if you could also replace the fiddle I added to your post (open the link, paste a create table t1(id,a,b,c)as values(1,2,1,1),(2,3,2,2)..., the same for t2, hit run and use the newly generated link.)

its fine, we cand use random data, the data in the image is just random numbers eitherway, so this would do fiddle

@MarioOrozco It's really easier if you make one small but clear example and double-check it by solving it manually and adding the result. Posting data and code as images isn't just unhelpful, it's unwelcome and against the rules and the fact that the picture you posted is inconsistent and incomplete doesn't help. It's fine if you replace it with create table..as values.. with a few rows and the expected result is thought-through and consistent with that input. It's easier for everyone to understand your logic based on the description if you add even a tiny but reliable input+output example.

Done, sorry didnt tought it was such a big deal since its just an illustrative example of my issue fiddle

@MarioOrozco Thanks for adding the input but the only example result is still in the picture and it doesn't look consistent with it: there are 9 rows where t2.b=2 and 4 of them also hold t2.a=3 but for some reason you showed the correct cnt2=3. Even if you wanted to also use the a>b and c>1.5 when counting matching t2's, it's still 4 not 3. An MRE is a basic requirement on StackOverflow - it's not being picky, it's trying to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Here are a few examples but I'd appreciate if you could clarify the inconsistency in the example result. These examples have vastly different performance.
